# I cannot control the number of chains and jobs in pymc3

Tags: pymc, pymc3

I am trying to use pymc3 to generate some samples from a GMM distribution, here is my code:

```
w = sp.array([.3, .6, 0.1])

w = sp.array([.3, .6, 0.1])

mu = sp.array([-2, 1, 4])

sd = sp.array([1, 0.5, 0.5])

with pm.Model() as model:
    pm.NormalMixture('x', w=w, mu=mu, sd=sd)
    step = pm.Metropolis(tune=False, S=sp.array([1])) 
    trace = pm.sampling.sample(1000, step=step, start={'x':5}, 
    chain=10, cores=1, tune=0)
result = trace['x']
```

However, no matter what I do with "chain" and "cores", I get the following :

Multiprocess sampling (2 chains in 2 jobs)

Metropolis: [x]

100%|██████████| 1000/1000 [00:00<00:00, 1407.68it/s]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `chains`, and `njobs`. Note that setting `n_chains` with 1000 samples means you will actually get `n_chains * 1000` total draws from your model.  The `njobs` argument is passed to `joblib`, which figures out how to distribute those chains on your machine.

`cores` will be accepted starting with PyMC 3.4 (or on master as of January, 2018).  It is A Bad Thing that `sample` accepts keyword arguments and silently does nothing with them. That would be a useful contribution, or issue, in the project.

Comment: Thanks, I changed both of them. `njobs` works. However, still `nchains` does not work: I want to get one chain in one job. Here is the new code `trace = pm.sampling.sample(500, step=step, start={'x':5}, njobs=1, nchains=1, tune=0)`

Comment: My mistake - should have been `chains`.  I have updated the answer.